# While Plotting x-y contour, it plot a single point

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-compiler

I have tried many times to create an `x` and `y` plot.
Every time I get only a point, and not a contour which I want. It should be the arc of a circle or an ellipse.

My current Matlab code:

```
a = 8*pi/5;    
u = 1;    
z=0.15;

x = cosh(u)*sqrt(1 - (sin(a)*sin(a)*sinh(u)*sinh(u))/square((sqrt(1-z)*cosh(u) + cos(a))));

y= -1*((sinh(u)*sinh(u)*sin(a))/(sqrt(1-z)*cosh(u) + cos(a)));

plot(x,y,'o')
```

assume any value of `u`.

Comment: `u` is a scalar value, therefore both `x` and `y` are both scalar values, not vectors... Of course the plot is only a point...

Answer (score 3):

`u` is a scalar, so you are plotting single points.

Make `u` an array

```
a = 8*pi/5;    
u = 1:0.02:2;    % Your u values as an array
z = 0.15;
```

And make your operations element-wise in the `x` and `y` calculations

```
x = cosh(u).*sqrt(1 - (sin(a).*sin(a).*sinh(u).*sinh(u))./square((sqrt(1-z).*cosh(u) + cos(a))));

y= -1.*((sinh(u).*sinh(u).*sin(a))./(sqrt(1-z).*cosh(u) + cos(a)));
```

Use a line style which isn't just a point (like `'o'` is), for instance for a line with circles at each value you can use

```
plot(x,y,'-o')
```

---

Note: your `x` and `y` calculations give complex results for these values, and `plot` ignores imaginary parts of the inputs by default.

Comment: That depends how you want to plot it. If you have complex `x` *and* `y`, then you have 4 dimensions which can't easily be displayed. If only one is complex then use `plot3` for a 3D plot, where one of the dimensions is complex... It depends entirely what your expected output is.

Comment: the code after fix still does not look like the image.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot `u` should be an array to get the points in the plot

```
a = 8*pi/5;  
% assigning an array from 1 to 2 with stepsize = 0.1 
u = 1:0.02:2;
z = 0.15;
```

Since, `u` is an array the multiplication should be element-wise`(.*)`

```
x = cosh(u).*sqrt(1 - (sin(a).*sin(a).*sinh(u).*sinh(u))./square((sqrt(1-z).*cosh(u) + cos(a))));

y= -1.*((sinh(u).*sinh(u).*sin(a))./(sqrt(1-z).*cosh(u) + cos(a)));

% Ignoring the complex value since it only provide some phase 
plot(abs(x),abs(y),'r');
hold on
plot(real(x),real(y),'g')
legend('abs values','real Values')
```

[image: The Image of the plot of the above-executed code is shown here]